# Unable to Convert TimeInterval 1589485565000 to Date in Swift

Tags: swift

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 1589485565000) 
let formatter = DateFormatter() formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a" 
let myString = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: I just got `"52369/10/17 13:03:20 PM"` with this exact same code in Xcode 11.5.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you have is the milliseconds since 1970. So you need to divide your value by 1000. You are using the wrong initializer `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` is "The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001."

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(1589485565000) / 1000 )
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a"
let string = formatter.string(from: date)  // "2020/05/14 16:46:05 PM"
```